# Reset kernel with generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator

Why my code with generator with any batch_sizes will reset and my Ram is going to fill

import some important libraries

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

load and some spliting data

```
cifar10_data = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = cifar10_data.load_data()

CLASS_NAMES= ['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']

validation_images, validation_labels = train_images[:5000], train_labels[:5000]
train_images, train_labels = train_images[5000:], train_labels[5000:]
```

using tf.data form and build some pairs of data

```
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images, train_labels))
test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_images, test_labels))
validation_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((validation_images, validation_labels))
```

define a preprocessing

```
def process_images(image, label, size=227):
    # Normalize images to have a mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1
    image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(image)
    # Resize images from 32x32 to 277x277
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (227,227))
    return image, label
```

using tf.data for understanding size of data

```
train_ds_size = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(train_ds).numpy()
test_ds_size = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(test_ds).numpy()
validation_ds_size = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(validation_ds).numpy()

print("Training data size:", train_ds_size)
print("Test data size:", test_ds_size)
print("Validation data size:", validation_ds_size)
```

using tf.data methods for generating data in batch size = 64

```
train_ds = (train_ds
                  .map(process_images)
                  .shuffle(buffer_size=train_ds_size)
                  .batch(batch_size=64, drop_remainder=True))
test_ds = (test_ds
                  .map(process_images)
                  .shuffle(buffer_size=train_ds_size)
                  .batch(batch_size=64, drop_remainder=True))
validation_ds = (validation_ds
                  .map(process_images)
                  .shuffle(buffer_size=train_ds_size)
                  .batch(batch_size=64, drop_remainder=True))
```

define the model

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=96, kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(4,4), activation='relu', input_shape=(227,227,3)),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(5,5), strides=(1,1), activation='relu', padding="same"),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), activation='relu', padding="same"),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), activation='relu', padding="same"),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), activation='relu', padding="same"),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
```

compile the model

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])
# model.summary()
```

fit the model on dataset

```
history = model.fit(train_ds,
          epochs=1,
          validation_data=validation_ds, verbose=1,
          validation_freq=1)
```

How can I use generator like this code without problem
actually I need to use a generator in my code to solve memory problem but I don't know how to use this type of generator

Comment: Why are you resizing images from 32x32 to 227x227? This literally makes no sense, models on CIFAR10 work directly on the 32x32 sized images.

Comment: Hi thanks for your attention
I just wanted to test my generator on it and after test I saw It reset
I need to know how to use generators in machine learning and I need some references to understand deeply my problem

Comment: Sure but that does not answer what I asked, using 32x32 images will significantly reduce memory use.

Comment: I know what do you mean
but I want to have this problem my problem is filling my memory
I want to solve this problem with generators
I know I can reduce size of images but I don't want this solution

Comment: Why you do not want this solution? Its literally not needed to upscale your images, it will not increase accuracy or anything. Note that you created the memory problem by upscaling the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must reduce shuffle buffer size.

Answer (score 0):

Its just cause of stack of dense layers with so many units (neurons) that will lead into overflow and OOM and as estimated for this model, the dense layers will contain 37752832  and  16781312 trainable parameters which is really enormous model.

So try out again with less units for dense layers, notice the most important thing in convolution models is that the dense layers are just for classifying the extracted feature maps, so its not needed to define dense layers with so many units, so emphasis on defining best model based on convolution base.

Comment: Actually I tried with less than parameters 4,344,650 trainable parameters and it reset again I think reset kernel is for my input shape it is so big and with 64 batch size it is going to fill my memory and I don't know I need to learn about generator and I didn't find any good references for it